# CoreData same object has different URIRepresentations

Tags: core-data

I have an app that uses CoreData. There are several entities - user, conversation, message. It looks like this:

- Conversation: (1-many) Message (the messages in a conversation)
- Conversation: (many-many) User (the users in a conversation)
- Message (1-1) User (the sender of a message)

I have a strange situation where sometimes the sender of a message is an empty database object even though the same user in the conversation is not empty. I've looked at the two user objects and they have a very similar URI representation:

```
message.user (empty)
x-coredata://68B3C0B2-8441-4BD7-BA58-358959F87947/CDUser/p7

vs:

conversation.users[0] (not empty)
x-coredata://68B3C0B2-8441-4BD7-BA58-358959F87947/CDUser/p4
```

I'm not sure what the p7 vs p4 refers to and why CoreData would create a duplicate of the entity.

So there are two versions of the same database entity. My CoreData setup looks like this:

```
    _parentMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    _parentMoc.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    
    _mainMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    _mainMoc.parentContext = _parentMoc;
    _mainMoc.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = YES;
    _mainMoc.undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];

    _backgroundMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    _backgroundMoc.parentContext = _mainMoc;
    _backgroundMoc.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = YES;
```

What I don't understand is why I have one entity duplicated... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the conversations contains users, that user doesn't necessarily have to send the message right? Maybe the user that send the message has been deleted or you haven't correctly added that user to the message?

Comment: I think that it is the same user entity in both cases since the actual ID part of the URI is the same. I don't understand what the /p[x] refers to and why it's different.

Comment: They are different objects: the “/CDUser/p7” is all part of the unique ID.  The preceding part is common to all objects in the same store.

Comment: The p4 and p7 mean that they’re different instances. The UUID identifies the persistent store file.